# Including Psyco Files in distribution

Tags: python, windows, distribution, packaging, psyco

I'm developing a game server in python. Since this server is distributed to other people who don't have much coding experience(or common sense) I try to include any modules I can into a pre-reqs folder in the project, so users can run the code without installing things. I tried out python on my program, and noticed a speed increase. I tried including the files from the psyco folder in the pre reqs folder, but my users got errors about psyco not being installed. So now I'm wondering, is it possible to include psyco with my package, and if so, what files and other things need to be included?

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to distribute Python packages is to use [distutils](http://docs.python.org/library/distutils.html) (for now anyway). You can specify psyco as a dependency and when people install your package, it will get pulled in.

Comment: Yes.. But since Psyco has some C++ files, wouldn't distutils need Microsoft Visual C++ compiler? If so, the compiler is something they would have to install, and since I'm trying to avoid users installing anything else, that would be contrary to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Well, then perhaps you can consider using something like [Py2Exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) to compile your entire app into a single windows executable? Python interpreter included.

Comment: Also note that 99% of linux installations have a compiler. So you should probably distribute your script as distutils if you want it to run on linux, since py2exe can't

Comment: @Falmarri: There's more phones with linux than desktop computers now, and Android does not come with a C compiler. Be careful with wording.